# linux / virtual/physical page sizes

Tags: linux, page-size

Is the page size constant? To be more specific , getconf PAGE_SIZE gives 4096, fair enough. But can this change through a program's runtime? Or is it constant throughout the entire OS process spawn. I.e. , is it possible for a process to have 1024 and 2048 AND 4096 page sizes? Let's just talk virtual page sizes for now. But going further is it possible for a virtual page to span a physical page of greater size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible for a process to use more than one pagesize. On newer kernels this may even happen without notice, see [Andrea Arcangelis transparent huge pages](http://lwn.net/Articles/423584/).

Other than that, you can request memory with a different (usually larger) page size over [hugetlbfs](http://lwn.net/Articles/374424/).

The main reason for having big pages is performance, the TLB in the processor is very limited in size, and fewer but bigger pages mean more hits.